# C# performance question: typeof(MyClass) vs. this.GetType()

Tags: c#, .net, performance

In the first example of the [log4net configuration manual](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html) the author uses `typeof(MyApp)` to get the type of the containing class `MyApp`. Is there a reason not to use `this.GetType()`, performance-wise? Because it seems to me that `this.GetType()` is much safer from potential copy-paste errors when copying into another class.

Comment: When you have no instance, only TYPEOF is available, isn't it?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

`typeof(Foo)` is a static type lookup; essentially it occurs at compile time, so you only get the explicitly named type.

`GetType()` is a dynamic type lookup; it's a virtual method that gets called at runtime and will give you the exact type even if you are using polymorphism. So it's "slower", theoretically, but it's giving you something you can't get from `typeof(T)`. If you need one or the other for your design, the speed isn't going to be a factor.

Answer (score 16):

Performance issues aside, in the provided example, `GetType` isn't even an option because it is an *instance* method; it can't be called from a field-initializer.  In any case, since the intent is to initialize a *static* field from a static 'context', logically  a `this` reference can't be  available - so going down the static-constructor route wouldn't help with allowing `GetType` either.

```
// Can't use GetType() - the this reference is not available.
private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyApp));
```

Comment: You're right, how stupid of me not to notice the `static` keyword :)

Comment: @Ani, but what about performance, when both the object and the type name are known?